# Combine all files in all folders in a directory

Tags: bash

So I have a folder called Genomes, within this folder I have 3000 folders all with 1 file within them. I want to combine all of these files into one large file. I figure there should be a way to do this in bash but I am unsure how to go about it.

Comment: You mean you want to concatenate all the files? Do you require them concatenated into any particular order? Do your folders go any deeper than just one level below `Genomes`? Please provide some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(
cd Genomes
cat */* > ../Genomes-combined-data
)
```

This creates a single file at the same level as the `Genomes` directory containing the concatenation of all the files.

The only problem might be the length of the argument list.  If that's a problem, then (assuming there are no files — just directories — in the `Genomes` directory):

```
find Genomes -type f -exec cat {} + > Genomes-combined-data
```

This uses `find` to determine the names and split the list into manageable chunks.  The net result is the essentially same in that you will have a single file containing all the data that was previously in 3000 separate files.  However, as [Michał Górny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165333/micha%c5%82-g%c3%b3rny) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513299/combine-all-files-in-all-folders-in-a-directory/26513383#comment41656658_26513383), the order of the data in the files will probably be different compared with using `*/*`.  If necessary, you can futz with `find ... -print0` piped into `sort -z` piped into `xargs -0 cat` to deal with any spaces or newlines in the names.  All those are not completely standard extensions to the POSIX tools.

```
find Genomes -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat > Genomes-combined-data
```

If you know you have sane names, you can simply use:

```
find Genomes -type f -print | sort | xargs cat > Genomes-combined-data
```

and you can make the sort criteria as complex as you like.

You can place the output file in any convenient location, of course.  Don't place the output file where `find` would find it — that would lead to a full disk unless you're extremely lucky.

Comment: The net result *isn't* the same. `*/*` sorts files lexically, `find` doesn't :).

Comment: @MichałGórny: OK, fair comment.

Comment: Use `>>` to append instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that will sort all file names, and concatenate their contents into one file (`Genomes-all`) with a header for each indicating their name:

```
(find Genomes -type f | sort | xargs tail -n +1) > Genomes-all
```